# @can and @auth directives doesn't work in Lumen with GraphQL

Tags: graphql, lumen

I am trying to implement [lighthouse graphql](https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse) to my Lumen project as a GraphQL server.

`@can` directive returns like this error:
`Call to a member function can() on null`. And `@auth` directives return `null` despite of I have logged in before.

Also, I have followed [this](http://kikoseijo.com/laravel-lumen-graphql-server-for-react-relay-modern/) article to implement.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.